# Only Allow To Access Folders Via Code With .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to hide my `uploads` folder but i want to access it via php . Is this possible with `.htaccess` ?
I tried something but didn't worked.

```
    <files "/uploads">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
    </files>

    <folders uploads>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
    </folders>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, but it depends on what version of Apache you're using also.

The above method you're trying is if you want to block access to a specific file, if you want to block a folder, then add your `.htaccess` file to that folder and just use:

Below 2.4:

```
deny from all
```

2.4 or above:

```
Require all denied
```

Comment: Thanks. I seems ok but my codes will access folder right?

Comment: How do you mean? What the above does will stop people from accessing your `uploads` folder. You will still be able to access it.

Comment: This code locks directly access to folder but it's not hiding if you know files names . uploads/asd.pdf etc. Is there anyway to hide files too?

Comment: Yes, that is when you would use `<files asd.pdf>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>` obviously changing if your Apache 2.4 or higher.

Comment: You can also use `<FilesMatch ".pdf">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>` if you have a lot of the same file.

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

You can just upload a .htaccess to the folder that you want to block with the following:

```
Deny from all
```

If there is some issue, add:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

It worked well for me.

**Original answer**

Try:

```
<Directory "/uploads">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

**EDIT:**

The code above will deny all except the local ip (of your server).

As thickguru said, it also depends on your apache version. Here are some other ways to do it:

```
<Directory "/uploads">
    Require local
</Directory>
```

It will only allow if requested by the server (your script or somewhat on the server).

Or:

```
<Directory "/uploads">
    Require ip 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

The same as above, but using the local adress. You can also add other ips to it. All the ips that you add there will be allowed to access the folder.

Comment: i tried all them now. First one locked whole site and the other ones not worked..

Comment: @VNFP Upload a .htaccess file to the folder that you want to restrict with the following: "Deny from all".

Comment: @VNFP this is working well for me and I don't have to block the access to the files on .htaccess too, since they are yet.